# Match word only when prefix does not exist

Tags: regex

In most coding languages, comments can be either singular or multiline. For example,

```
// this is a single line comment
public class A {}

/*
 this is multiline
*/
public class B {}
```

The comment needs to precede the class declaration, with no extra newlines in between.

I am writing a regex to match instances of `class`es where no comment is added. I have the following regex but unsure of how to extend it such that `class` is only matched if no comment is attached to it previously:

```
(\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*([^\*]|\*[^\/])*\*\/)\n((.*)?(class))
```

As an example, the following would be matched:

```
public class A {}

private final class B {}

private class C {}

public final class D {}
```

But not these:

```
// Single line comment
private final class B {}

/* Multiline comment */
public class B {}
```

Comment: A quick look at your regex seems to be reduced to this `(//[^\n]*|/\*([^*]|\*[^/])*\*/)\n((.*)(class))` Not saying it meets your needs yet.

Comment: Must `/*`be at the beginning of a line? If no, must it be preceded in the line only by whitespace? What if there are one or more lines of whitespace between the end of the comment and the line containing the class statement? What about `public class A {}  // A is great!`? I suggest you clarify by editing the question rather than doing so in a comment.

Comment: can your files contain string definitions? eg. `"this is a string containing a url http://example, not a comment"`

Comment: @jhnc Yes, it is possible. Those should not be triggered. Only comments that are preceding class declarations

Answer (score -2):

The unwanted text in Group1 is what to discard.
Group 2 is what to keep.
If you use PCRE type engine you can use *(*SKIP)(*FAIL)* instead of matching the unwanted text.

Matching the unwanted text is the only way to move past this text and acts like a filter.

```
(?m)(?:((?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?)(?:\r?\n)(?:^.*?class.*)?|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'))|(^.*?class.*))
```

https://regex101.com/r/m5ms1J/1

```
 (?m)
 (?:
    (                                # (1 start), Comments or quotes
       (?:                              # Start /* .. */ comment
          /\*
          [^*]* \*+
          (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
          /                                # End /* .. */ comment
        | 
          //                               # Start // comment
          (?:                              # Possible line-continuation
             [^\\] 
           | \\ 
             (?: \r? \n )?
          )*?
          
       )
       (?: \r? \n )
       (?: ^ .*? class .* )?
       
     |                                 # Non - comments 
       (?:
          "
          (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
          "
        | '
          (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
          ' 
       )
    )                                # (1 end)
  | 
    ( ^ .*? class .* )               # (2)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! It seems however that this regex would unexpectedly catch strings in the code. So if there was a string variable defined like `let x = "hello"` this would match.

Comment: @najm You're welcome. But, it's a well known fact that quoted string literals can contain comment syntax. Effectively a false positive. Like `let x = "hello /*not a comment start"` . By matching quotes the current position is advanced past them.